# want to insert average values of month not exist current year from regular data entry

Tags: mysql, sql

want  to insert average values of month  not exist current year  from regular data entry.current year values should not insert to table avg_month_val1 from reg_data3 table.

```
INSERT INTO 
    `clima_data`.`avg_month_val1` ( 
        `year` , 
        `month` , 
        `evep` , 
        `sunshine_hrs` , 
        `rainfall` , 
        `max_temp` , 
        `min_temp` ) 
    SELECT 
        year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as year,
        month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as month,
        round(avg(evep)),
        round(Avg(sunshine_hrs)),
        round(sum(rainfall)),
        round(AVG(max_temp)),
        round(avg(min_temp)) 
    FROM 
        reg_data 
    GROUP BY 
        year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')),
        month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'));
```

Comment: What you are saying is not clear.

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ i enter daily data in to reg_data3 table from this query i want to insert average values of that data with year and month. but current year values shoul not be insert to average table.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a `WHERE` condition to exclude the current year. If you want past years' data only you can change `!=` operator to `<`.

Another point: date is reserved word for mysql's [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function. So you should make "*weird quoting*"  for `date` like

```
`date`
```

Your probable solution is the following:

```
INSERT INTO 
    `clima_data`.`avg_month_val1` ( 
        `year` , 
        `month` , 
        `evep` , 
        `sunshine_hrs` , 
        `rainfall` , 
        `max_temp` , 
        `min_temp` ) 
    SELECT 
        YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y'))as year,
        YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y'))as month,
        ROUND(AVG(evep)),
        ROUND(AVG(sunshine_hrs)),
        ROUND(SUM(rainfall)),
        ROUND(AVG(max_temp)),
        ROUND(AVG(min_temp)) 
    FROM 
        reg_data 
    WHERE 
        YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) !=  YEAR(CURDATE())
    GROUP BY 
        YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y')),
        MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y'));
```

Comment: I suggest to not use proprietary ``<>``, rather use ``!=``